# How to get specific part of JSON text

Tags: javascript, json

I have a PHP file that creates a JSON text of my MySQL data.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>Sample Page</title>
  <script>
     var settings = {
       "async": true,
       "crossDomain": true,
       "url": "http://www.hotel1.com/Experiment/Api/Json1.php?ID=1",
       "method": "GET"
     }

     $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
       console.log(response);
       console.log(response.something.something)
     });
  </script>
```

Above you can see my code

```
      [
 {
      "Worker1": {
          "ID :": "1",
         "Username": "Tony"
       }
 }
]
```

Above you can see my JSON text that is being printed. My problem is I want to know how to select ID from the JSON text in JavaScript. As shown above. When I try to say response.Worker1.ID it give me an error saying ID is undefined.

Can someone help me fix my mistake?

Comment: Is the `response` json string or json object? If its a "json string" then either modify "settings" to auto parse into json object, or call `JSON.parse()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the JSON into a javascript object. Use `JSON.parse()`, as follows:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>Sample Page</title>
  <script>
     var settings = {
       "async": true,
       "crossDomain": true,
       "url": "http://www.hotel1.com/Experiment/Api/Json1.php?ID=1",
       "method": "GET"
     }

     $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
       response = JSON.parse(response); // the change is here
       console.log(response);
       console.log(response.something.something)
     });
  </script>
```

Also bear in mind that your "sample json" returns an array, hence the square brackets `[]`. So to access, you would do `response[0].something`.

Comment: After parsing it how do extract only the ID of worker1

Comment: Provided you are using this solution, then a `console.log(response)` will show you the data structure. If I go by your sample data however, then that would likely be `response[0].Worker1.ID`

Comment: @ GetSet Now I have a textbox that i want the user to enter Example: Worker1 in the textbox and show the result. ho do I do that.

Comment: Example: response[index].variable.ID

Comment: So we can continue on this other topic, open new thread/question with your code sample on this new stuff. That way we can focus on the user-interface aspects.

Comment: @ GetSet I have made a new Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65266482/using-user-input-to-show-the-value-of-json  here is the link

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not referencing the json object attribute 'ID' properly. So close! Try the below code and LMK how that works:

[ { "Worker1": { "ID :": "1", "Username": "Tony" } } ]

```
console.log(response[Worker1].ID)
```

Comment: This is not how to read javascript objects.

Comment: MCA i tried it but it says Worker1 is not defined

Comment: try running console.log(typeof response) and LMK if what you are grabbing is a JSON object or a string!

Comment: MCA. I get type string

Comment: MCA. Do you know how do i parse to json

Comment: JSON.parse(response) and then after you do that you can console.log it. so basically you could do console.log(JSON.parse(response.something.something))