# Using user input to show the value of json

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json script on my server. I have three text fields.

```html
<label>Index</label><input type="text" id="index" /><br/>
<label>Worker#</label><input type="text" id="Worker_ID" /><br/>
<label>Worker Value</label><input type="text" id="worker_value" /><br/>
<button onclick="Fetch_Result()">Search</button>
```

I have script that shows me the specific value of json text

```
<script>
```

function Fetch_Result() {

```
  var index = document.getElementById("index").value;
  var Value = document.getElementById("Worker_ID").value;
  var x = document.getElementById("worker_value").value;

  var settings = {
     "async": true,
     "crossDomain": true,
     "url": "http://www.hotel1.com/Experiment/Api/Json1.php",
     "method": "GET"
  }

  $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
     response = JSON.parse(response); // the change is here
     //console.log(response);
     console.log(response[index].x.ID);
  });
```

}

```
{
    "Worker1": {
        "ID :": "1",
        "Username": "Tony"
    }
```

This is my json text. I am having trouble with asking the user to enter the Worker number in the text box. I want to know how do i replace the x and the ID with the textbox values. So that i don't have to keep writing code for new Workers.

Example: console.log(response[index].userinput1.userinput2);

userinput1 is the Worker number like: Worker1, Worker2, ....
userinput2 is the value of Worker number like: ID, Username,...

Can some one help me

Comment: Do you want to send a post request to server to save changes or what?

Comment: No @KienHT I want the user to input the values in the textboxes then show the results in the console for testing

Comment: I thought you did it, `console.log(response[index].x.ID);`?

Comment: @KienHT. I want to replace x and ID with the textbox values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i can't add comment since my score is below 50. but this is how you do it:

```
console.log(response[index][id])
console.log(response[index][username])
```

Comment: it worked. I think you wrote this one console.log(response[index][Value_ID][x])

Comment: `console.log(response[index][Value_ID][x]` will work if your data is like this: `response={index: { value_id: { x : "something} } }` .